# Theming HTML5 canvas along with rest of site

Tags: asp.net, canvas, gulp, less

I'm working on theming a web app, and I ran into a problem with an angular directive that is being used. It's called angular-knob, and it uses an HTML5 canvas to display a progress bar input. Since it's a canvas, you have to tell it the color in JavaScript instead of CSS. This is the problem.

The rest of the site is themed based on a set of LESS variables. I would like the canvas to be the color of `@brand-primary` from the `variables.less` file, which could also be overridden in other `theme-*.less` files. I haven't found a good solution to this yet, but these are some of the ideas I've had:

- Parse the variables from the LESS file with some kind of ASP.Net utility (haven't found anything that would do this for me) to get the variable names and then render them to the client in a JavaScript variable (which I could then put in an angular service)
- Have gulp parse the variables from the LESS file (again, haven't found any npm packages that would do this for me) and create a script that puts the variables in with the JavaScript bundle.

Like I said, I haven't found any LESS file parsing utilities for ASP.Net or npm that would get me access to the LESS variables.

How would you tackle this kind of problem? Has anyone else had to handle something like this?

Comment: After your page has loaded and after your elements are color-styled, you can read the background color of one of those elements using [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Then apply that fetched color to your angular-knob in javascript.

Comment: Good thing there are people as talented as MarkE out there, I would have said, tough luck :)

Comment: @markE I had actually thought thought about that, but I was hoping there was a better solution. I may have no choice though.